# Pass array in HTTP request body

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to pass array like this in my request:

```
{
"ids": ["5ed7603ab05efe0004286d19", "5ed7608ab05efe0004286d1a"]
}
```

I did like that but I am not sure the server is getting as I intended:

```
    request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: ids, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `Dictionary` for this purpose. Here's how:

```
let dictionary = ["ids": ["5ed7603ab05efe0004286d19", "5ed7608ab05efe0004286d1a"]]
request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

Suggestion: The modern approach would be to use `JSONEncoder()`. You could google this, there are plenty of solutions online. If you're still struggling you can ask for the method in the comments, I'll help you figure out.

Update: How you can implement Swift's `JSONEncoder` API in your code.

```
let dictionary = ["ids": ["5ed7603ab05efe0004286d19", "5ed7608ab05efe0004286d1a"]]
request.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(dictionary)
```

Using a struct would be much safer. Here's how:

```
typealias ID = String
struct MyRequestModel: Codable { var ids: [ID] }

let myRequestModel = MyRequestModel(ids: ["5ed7603ab05efe0004286d19", "5ed7608ab05efe0004286d1a"])
request.httpBody   = try JSONEncoder().encode(myRequestModel)
```

Note: Usage of type-alias is optional it just adds a bit of readability to your code, as is the usage of `JSONDecoder`.

Comment: Note: `.prettyPrinted` shouldn't be useful. This adds unnecessary info that is useful only for the human brain.

Comment: Yeah, you're right it's just a pretty visual formatting.

Comment: You're welcome. As you move forward in ios development you should check-out `JSONEncoder` API as well which is safer and Swifty.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode using `JSONEncoder`;

```
let yourList = ["5ed7603ab05efe0004286d19", "5ed7608ab05efe0004286d1a"]

struct DataModel: Encodable {
    var ids: [String]
}

let data = DataModel(ids: yourList)
let encodedData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(data)

// JSON string value
let jsonString = String(data: encodedData, encoding: .utf8)
```